# Searching for a name in database and deleting the entry

Tags: java, sql, database, search

I'm making a Java program where I can make a local cookbook using Java and using SQL commands to access a database. I'm trying to delete a database entry by inputting the name into a text field and then delete the matching entry in the database with the same name. I'm having a weird error where it says "executeQuery()" cannot be used as an update but I still have the update method there. I would really appreciate it if someone could find out what I need to do to fix this.

Thanks!

```
    /** Creates new form deleteRecipe */
    public deleteRecipe() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnBack = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txtName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        txtName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtNameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("What Recipe do you want to delete?");

        btnDelete.setText("Delete!");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnBack.setText("Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBackActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtName)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(199, 199, 199)
                        .addComponent(btnDelete, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(btnBack)))
                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(btnBack)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(btnDelete, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void btnBackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        this.dispose(); 
        CookbookApp ca = new CookbookApp();
        ca.setVisible(true);
    }                                       

    private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        ArrayList<Cookbook  > recipes = new ArrayList();
        String name = txtName.getText();
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cookbook";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String query = "INSERT into RECIPES(NAME, SUBCATEGORY, CATEGORY, INGREDIENTS, INSTRUCTIONS, MODIFICATIONS) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            Cookbook recipe;

            while (rs.next()) {
                recipe = new Cookbook(rs.getString("NAME"), rs.getString("SUBCATEGORY"), rs.getString("CATEGORY"), rs.getString("INGREDIENTS"), rs.getString("INSTRUCTIONS"), rs.getString("MODIFICATIONS"));
                if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                recipes.remove(recipe);
            }
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

//    }
//     public ArrayList<Cookbook> recipes() {
//        ArrayList<Cookbook  > recipes = new ArrayList();
//        
//        try {
//            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cookbook";
//            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
//            String query = "SELECT * FROM RECIPES";
//            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
//            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
//
//            Cookbook recipe;
//            
//            pst.setString(1, name);
//            
//            
//            while (rs.next()) {
//                recipe = new Cookbook(rs.getString("NAME"), rs.getString("SUBCATEGORY"), rs.getString("CATEGORY"), rs.getString("INGREDIENTS"), rs.getString("INSTRUCTIONS"), rs.getString("MODIFICATIONS"));
//                if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(name))
//                recipes.remove(recipe);
//            }
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
//        }
//        return recipes;
//    
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deleteRecipe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deleteRecipe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deleteRecipe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deleteRecipe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new deleteRecipe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnBack;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDelete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtName;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you try to execute the *INSERT* SQL statement with the *executeQuery* method.

When you want to **update** your database (create, update, delete), you have to call *executeUpdate*.

If you want to **read** from the database, you can do this with the *executeQuery* method.

Also, I don't think that your delete method is doing what you want. It inserts a new entry to the database instead of deleting one.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to figure that one out as well, but I think I need to figure out how to search for the name and match it with the one in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of using the incorrect method for what you intend.

`execute` - Is used when you need to **execute** a DB command such as `Create Table` or `exe st_calc_taxes`

`executeUpdate` - Is used when you need to `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`

`executeQuery` - Is used when you need to `SELECT`

In these simple matters I would recommend referencing the documentation for these commands. A simple web search revealed [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-execute-executequery-and-executeupdate-methods-in-jdbc) which outlined the details above.